# How to detect completion with unknown concurrent Task pushing & pulling ConcurrentQueue<T>

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, task, task-parallel-library

Few days ago I tried to perform a fast search on my disks do few things like, Attributes, Extensions, perform change inside files etc ...

The idea was to make it with really few limitation/lock in order to avoid "latency" for big file or directory with a lots of files inside etc ...
I know it's far for "Best Practices", since i'm not using things like "MaxDegreeOfParallelism" or the Pulling loop with "while(true)"

Even though, the code is running quite fast since we have the architecture to support it.

I tried to move to code to a dummy console project if anybody would like to check what's going on.

```
class Program
{
    static ConcurrentQueue<String> dirToCheck;
    static ConcurrentQueue<String> fileToCheck;
    static int fileCount; //

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Initialize();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ScanDirectories(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ScanFiles(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Initialize()
    {
        //Instantiate caches
        dirToCheck = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
        fileToCheck = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

        //Enqueue Directory to Scan here
        //Avoid to Enqueue Nested/Sub directories, else they are going to be dcan at least twice
        dirToCheck.Enqueue(@"C:\");

        //Initialize counters
        fileCount = 0;
    }

    static void ScanDirectories()
    {
        String dirToScan = null;

        while (true)
        {
            if (dirToCheck.TryDequeue(out dirToScan))
            {
                ExtractDirectories(dirToScan);
                ExtractFiles(dirToScan);
            }

            //Just here as a visual tracker to have some kind an idea about what's going on and where's the load
            Console.WriteLine(dirToCheck.Count + "\t\t" + fileToCheck.Count + "\t\t" + fileCount);
        }
    }

    static void ScanFiles()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            String fileToScan = null;
            if (fileToCheck.TryDequeue(out fileToScan))
            {
                CheckFileAsync(fileToScan);
            }
        }
    }

    private static Task ExtractDirectories(string dirToScan)
    {
        Task worker = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                Parallel.ForEach<String>(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dirToScan), (dirPath) =>
                {
                    dirToCheck.Enqueue(dirPath);
                });

            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

        return worker;
    }

    private static Task ExtractFiles(string dirToScan)
    {
        Task worker = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                Parallel.ForEach<String>(Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirToScan), (filePath) =>
                {
                    fileToCheck.Enqueue(filePath);
                });
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

        return worker;
    }

    static Task CheckFileAsync(String filePath)
    {
        Task worker = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //Add statement to play along with the file here
            Interlocked.Increment(ref fileCount);


            //WARNING !!! If your file fullname is too long this code may not be executed or may just crash
            //I just put a simple check 'cause i found 2 or 3 different error message between the framework & msdn documentation
            //"Full paths must not exceed 260 characters to maintain compatibility with Windows operating systems. For more information about this restriction, see the entry Long Paths in .NET in the BCL Team blog"
            if (filePath.Length > 260)
                return;
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);

            //Add statement here to use FileInfo

        }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

        return worker;
    }
}
```

Problems:
How can I detect that i'm done with ScanDirectory?
Once it's done, I can manage to enqueue a String empty or whatever to the file queue, to exit it.
I know that if I use "AttachedToParent" I can have a Completion state on the parent Task, and then for example do something like "ContinueWith(()=> { /*SomeCode to notice the end*/})"
But still the parent task is doing Pulling and is stuck in a kind of infinite loop and each sub statement begin new Task.

On the other hand, I cannot simply test "Count" in each Queue 'cause I might have Flush the File List and Directory List but there might be another task that's going to call "EnumerateDirectory()".

I'm trying to find some kind of "reactive" solution and avoid some "if()" inside the loop that would be checked 80% of time for nothing since it's a simple while(true){} with AsyncCall.

PS: I know i could use TPL Dataflow, i'm not because i'm stuck on .net 4.0 for know, anyway, in .net 4.5 without dataflow since there's few improvement in the TPL, i'm still curious about it

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, you could use [`BlockingCollection<T>`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx)

`BlockingCollection<T>` is designed specifically for producer/consumer scenarios such as this, and provides a [CompleteAdding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086.aspx) method so the producer can notify the consumers that it has finished adding work.

Comment: If i'm not wrong the Consumer here is also the Producer, isn't it ?
Anyway, thanks for the advice, i'm gonna check & try it and let you know about it

Comment: @AlexandreHgs Potentially - though it's a bit muddled - I don't see where you're Enqueuing the items in your code.  That being said, this is fine - you can have a multiple producers and multiple consumers, and they can be the "same" threads/processes.

Comment: I looked a bit inside, I understand it can help me to get out of the Second pulling loop 
replacing with something like
while (dirToCheck.IsCompleted)
That way i'll exit the first loop, still my question is how do i detect how can i detect that i should call "dirToCheck.CompleteAdding()" since if you check the function "ExtractDirectories" it produces Items for the cirtoCheck Collection, but there's a huge chance that there's other task doing the same action at anytime.

One of the way i found, is to create a kind of array for my Tasks & use some .WaitAll(taskArray), but i'm not a fan at all.

Comment: So just to inform you, right now, maybe it's me but i think it was not helpfull, changing the collection type didn't leads me to an solution to break out from the Directory scanning loop.

I've tried a "kind of" recursive way calling the same method with an "attachedToParent" Option & .ContinueWith() to be sure all children were done, but i'm stuck with HUGE performance issues :(